# Why pluck() and where() methods not working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Why `pluck()` and `where()` methods not working?

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name:'sasha',
    time:'now',id:67            
})

var model = new Model;

var Model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name:'andrii',
    time:'now',id:45
})

var model2 = new Model2;

var Model3 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name:'sergii',
    time:'now',id:7            
})

var model3 = new Model3;

var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize:function(){console.log('init')}
})

var lib = new Library([model]);

lib.on('add',function(){
    console.log('add event')
})

lib.on('reset',function(){
    console.log('reset event')
})

lib.on('remove',function(){
    console.log('rremove event')
})

lib.push(model);
lib.push(model2);
lib.push(model3);
```

The `pluck` method is returning an array of `undefined` values when it should be returning the user names.

```
var names = lib.pluck("name");//[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

And `where` is returning an empty array instead of the model with id 7.

```
var wh = lib.where({id:7}) //[]
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? explain more please

Comment: Have you tried using the browser debugging tools to see what those objects actually look like?

Comment: Note: please pay more attention to your identation. It was hurting my eyes. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the way models work. You should use `Backbone.Model.extend` to define a model structure and then create new instances of it to represent data.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    /* your custom methods here */
});

var person1 = new Person({
    id: 67,
    name: 'sasha'
});

var person2 = new Person({
    id: 45,
    name: 'andrii'
});

var person3 = new Person({
    id: 7,
    name: 'sergii'
});
```

When you create a collection, you can define what model you are using:

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});

var lib = new Library();
lib.push(person1);
lib.push(person2);
lib.push(person3);
```

Using that it should work as expected:

```
var names = lib.pluck('name'); // ["sasha", "andrii", "sergii"]
var wh = lib.where({id: 7}); // [{"id": 7, ...}]
```